# Autoreload changes in modules that are added as a PySpark dependency in the Driver program

Tags: python, pyspark

I just noticed a subtle issue, when using `addPyFile` in PySpark and `autoreload` in Jupyter Notebooks.

What happens is that I have some code in modules that I use in PySpark UDFs, so (as far as I know) these modules need to be added as dependencies via `addPyFile`, so that they are available on executors. I zip these and use `addPyFile` after I set up a PySpark session.

However, after this, changes in those modules are not autoreloaded, e.g. when working in IPython/Jupyter Notebook. More specifically, running

```
import mypath.mymodule as mm
import imp
imp.reload(mm)
```

would normally show the path to the module, e.g. `<module 'mypath.mymodule' from 'C:\\project\\mypath\\mymodule.py'>`

However, after initializing Spark and submitting the zipped files via `addPyFile`, the above code would output something like: `<module 'mypath.mymodule' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\spark-....\\userFiles-...\\zipped_modules.zip\\mypath\\mymodule.py'>`

I.e. it seems like Spark switches to use the code from the zipped (and cached) modules (even in driver program), thus changes in the original module would not get autoreloaded in the driver program.

Is there a way to keep autoreloading the changes from the modules in the driver program in this scenario?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't ...