# Calling another custom Python function from Pyspark UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

Suppose you have a file, let's call it `udfs.py` and in it:

```py
def nested_f(x):
    return x + 1

def main_f(x):
    return nested_f(x) + 1
```

You then want to make a UDF out of the `main_f` function and run it on a dataframe:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.DataFrame([[1], [2], [3]], columns=['x'])
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

_udf = fn.udf(main_f, 'int')
df.withColumn('x1', _udf(df['x'])).show()
```

This works OK if we do this from within the same file as where the two functions are defined (`udfs.py`). However, trying to do this from **a different** file (say `main.py`) produces an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ...`:

```py
...
import udfs

_udf = fn.udf(udfs.main_f, 'int')
df.withColumn('x1', _udf(df['x'])).show()
```

I noticed that if I *actually nest* the `nested_f` inside the `main_f` like this:

```py
def main_f(x):
    def nested_f(x):
        return x + 1

    return nested_f(x) + 1
```

everything runs OK. However, my goal here is to have the logic nicely separated in multiple functions, which I can also test individually.

I *think* this can be solved by submitting the `udfs.py` file (or a whole zipped folder) to the executors using `spark.sparkContext.addPyFile('...udfs.py')`. However:

1. I find this a bit long-winded (esp. if you need to zip folders etc...)
2. This is not always easy/possible (e.g. `udfs.py` may be using lots of other modules which then also need to be submitted, leading to bit of chain reaction...)
3. There are some other inconveniences with `addPyFile` (e.g. [autoreload can stop working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391400/autoreload-changes-in-modules-that-are-added-as-a-pyspark-dependency-in-the-driv) etc )

So the **question** is: is there a way to do all of these at the same time:

- have the logic of the UDF nicely split to several Python functions
- use the UDF from a different file than where the logic is defined
- not needing to submit any dependencies using `addPyFile`

Bonus points for clarifying how this works/why this doesn't work!

Comment: Register your function as a UDF in udfs.py itself.

Comment: Have you tried that? I don't think that works.

Comment: @Ferrad: It works. Register your UDF in udfs.py and then import your registered udfs in other modules.

Answer (score 4):

For small (one or two local files) dependencies you can use --py-files and enumerate them, with something bigger or more dependencies - it's better to pack it in a zip or egg file.

File `udfs.py`:

```py
def my_function(*args, **kwargs):
    # code
```

File `main.py`:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from udfs import my_function

sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
my_udf = udf(my_function)

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "a"), (2, "b")])
df.withColumn("my_f", my_udf("..."))
```

For run:

```bash
pyspark --py-files /path/to/udfs.py
# or
spark-submit --py-files /path/to/udfs.py main.py
```

If you have written your own Python module or even third-party modules (which don't need C compilation), I personally needed it with `geoip2`, it's better to create a zip or egg file.

```bash
# pip with -t install all modules and dependencies in directory `src`
pip install geoip2 -t ./src
# Or from local directory
pip install ./my_module -t ./src

# Best is 
pip install -r requirements.txt -t ./src

# If you need add some additionals files
cp ./some_scripts/* ./src/

# And pack it
cd ./src
zip -r ../libs.zip .
cd ..

pyspark --py-files libs.zip
spark-submit --py-files libs.zip
```

**Be careful when using `pyspark --master yarn`** (possibly with other non-local master options), in pyspark shell with `--py-files`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/libs.zip')  # You can use relative path: .insert(0, 'libs.zip')
>>> import MyModule  # libs.zip/MyModule
```

**EDIT - The answer on question of how to get functions on executors without `addPyFile ()` and `--py-files`:**

It is necessary to have a given file with functions on individual executors. And reachable through PATH env.
Therefore, I would probably write a Python Module, which I then install on the executors and was available in the environment.

Comment: Thanks, a useful answer, although it is not exactly what I am after, seems like `--py-files` is just a CLI equivalent of `addPyFile` ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/38072930/1913724 ) . It may be that what I am asking for does not exist, in which case it would be nice to know why!

Comment: @Ferrard - **The answer on question of how to get functions on executors without `addPyFile ()` and `--py-files`:** It is necessary to have a given file with functions on individual executors. And reachable through PATH env. Therefore, I would probably write a Python Module, which I then install on the executors and was available in the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try organizing your methods inside a class as follows:

```
class temp_class:
    def nested_f(self, x):
      return x + 1

    def main_f(self, x):
      return self.nested_f(x) + 1
```

This may work!!